# Multiple dynamic select option lists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate 3 drop down exactly the same from each other but select name and option value. I found a simple javascript works fine for my demand; however, unable to make it work once I combo the select list. Below is what I have changed and no longer work correctly when changed. I'm not good with js so any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/   xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery1.7.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
var selectValues = {
    "nokia": {
        "N97": "http://www.google.com",
        "N93": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "motorola": {
        "M1": "http://www.ebay.com",
        "M2": "http://www.twitter.com"
    }
};
for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
    var $vendor+i = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
    var $model+i = $('select.model'+i);

    $vendor+i.change(function() {
        $model+i.empty().append(function() {
            var output = '';
            $.each(selectValues[$vendor+i.val()], function(key, value) {
                output += '<option value='+value+'>' + key + '</option>';
            });
            return output;
        });
    }).change();
}
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#download-link {
padding: 13px 15px 13px 15px;
font-size: larger;
font-decoration: underline;
background-color: #ffffbb;
border: 2px dashed red;
margin-top: 16px;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>  
<form action="?"  method="get">
<%for i=1 to 3%>
<select name="dvr_<%=i%>" class="mobile-vendor<%=i%>">
    <option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
    <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
    <option value="android">Android</option>
</select>

<select name="cam_<%=i%>" class="model<%=i%>">
    <option></option>
</select>
<BR />
<%next%>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change these lines:

```
var $vendor+i = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
var $model+i = $('select.model'+i);
```

to

```
var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
var $model = $('select.model'+i);
```

without the need to append the counter to the variable names. inside the function just refer to `$vendor` and `$model`

EDIT:
try this code

```
for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
    var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
    var $model = $('select.model'+i);

    $vendor.change(function() {
        var $o = $( this );
        $o.next().empty().append(function() {
            var output = '';
            $.each(selectValues[$o.val()], function(key, value) {
                output += '<option value='+value+'>' + key + '</option>';
            });
            return output;
        });
    }).change();
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the result was that the first 2 model selects were no longer appeared.  The third one works.

Comment: yup, I changed all $vendor+i and $model+i to $vendor and $model in the script code

Comment: there sould be 3 places to change. I've edited my answer, please check my solution

Comment: Actually now none of the select models work.  Please see preview here chimboo.com/test.asp

Comment: I tried again, but result has not changed.  I moved the 2 declared variables outside of the for loop but didn't help either.  BTW, thank you for your help and patient.

Comment: you are missing `});` at the end of the script

Comment: you are right.  The 3 models showed up again. but only the third one works. Please check the link to preview.

Comment: try to replace just the `for` loop in my answer. currently you have your old code

Comment: Awesome!!! it works now as it should.  Thank you very much.  I'd need to chew through your adjustment for a better understanding now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

the error is not only how they named their variaves?

```
var $vendor+i = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
```

would not be so alone?

```
var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor'+i);
```